# Why does Zoro always forget his sense of direction?

Tags: one-piece

Every single direction given to Zoro by anyone gets puzzled his mind and he gets lost in the end. He gets lost even when someone simply tells him to go straight.

At the end of the Dressrosa arc, Zoro was even mocked by Trafalgar D. Law for getting lost when going a short distance away. So, Law was forced to move him with his ROOM ability. Zoro himself looked very embarrassed at that time when Law mocked him.

Why is Zoro's sense of direction so poor to the point of being ridiculous? Is there an in-universe explanation?

Comment: It is undetermined as of now. We don't necessarily KNOW if it is canon because in the show it would say how Zoro uses the clouds for navigation. So it most likely IS canon but we don't know for sure. Hope this helps :).

Comment: @Tristan-_-  as mentioned by Matthew F in answer section, in the beginning of the show he can sense direction but maybe after getting Wado Ichimonji: One of the 21 Great Grade Meito. Forged by the legendary Wano swordsmith Shimotsuki Kozaburo, he is not able to recognize direction well, maybe it is because of early use of Haki embedded sword, because his new sword Enma has same abilities of Haki...

Comment: We still don't know a lot about Zoro's background and where he comes from (we can presume it is Wano) and the loss of direction could be something Oda will explain later on. For now it is a funny trait, but it could be more then that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no in-universe explanation. This is just a character trait that Oda gave Zoro for ... some reason. Maybe there's an explanation in SBS.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say if it's canon or not, but in one of the video games, there was a conversation between Zoro and Nami where Zoro said that he uses clouds as landmarks.

Comment: Please share the source of information.

Comment: I remember this too. It's from the show/manga, and it's when Nami was sick, which is the reason why Zoro was steering the ship.

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning of the show, they showed kid Zoro using his sense of direction, so it must have been something like hitting his head as a kid or being hung on a cross by some marine captain for a few days.

Answer (score -1):

Zoro's lack of directional sense could possibly be a result of the cursed sword that he wields: [Sandai Kitetsu](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Sandai_Kitetsu).

[image]

Although Zoro was able to prove that his luck was capable of warding off the curse, by gambling his arm, it's likely that whatever impact that the swords curse brings upon him is most likely partial active and comedic (although it could be more sinister and be connected to his sealed eyes).

Comment: didn't he have a bad sense of direction before acquiring the sword?